# How to uppercase $1 output

Tags: regex, textmate

I am trying to uppercase the output in a find/replace statement in TextMate. Here is what I have to isolate the text:

```
Find: (uv.+)
Replace: $1
```

How would I do: `"$1".upper()`

```
Input:
https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-us/movies/cid=uv0012-npvb22701_cn-0000000000307457

Desired Output:
https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-us/movies/cid=UV0012-NPVB22701_CN-0000000000307457
```

Comment: Why was this question tagged linux and unix?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, that worked and was the best solution.

Comment: It is written in the answer below already. Also, `\u` only turns to upper the *first* char of the backreference value, while `\U` will turn all of the chars that follow until `\E` to upper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the manual, section 20.4.2:

> It is possible to convert the next character to upper or lowercase by
>   prepending it with \u or \l. This is mainly useful when the next
>   character stems from a capture register. Example:
>
> ```
> Find: (<a.*?>)(.*?)(</a>) 
> Replace: $1\u$2$3
> ```
>
> You can also convert a
>   longer sequence to upper or lowercase by using \U or \L and then \E to
>   disable the case folding again. Example:
>
> ```
> Find: (<a.*?>)(.*?)(</a>) 
> Replace: $1\U$2\E$3
> ```

Comment: why does `\U$1` work in my case but `\u$1` does not?

Comment: @David542 Does Wiktor's comment to your question answer your comment here?